# Compling PHP from source on Windows 7, fatal error C1900

Tags: php, c, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am attempting to compile PHP from source on Windows 7 using windows sdk 6.1. I am receiving the following error when running nmake:

```
fatal error C1900: Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20080116' and 'P2' version '20070207'
LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\Bin\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2' 
Stop.
```

I have already run repair on Visual Studio 2010 to no avail. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I am compiling the C source not actual PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

Do yo really need to build from source PHP?

I mean, there's no need to build php from source, you can use a package such as XAMPP or WAMP. For practical reason I use XAMPP for PHP projects, because XAMPP runs on both Windows and Linux, so the only thing I need to do is a simple folder installation, then a simple LigHTTPD/Apache configuration and that's it.

But if you really want to compile PHP on Windows, you need to install the distributable version of Visual C++ 2008, I don't know why the 2010 version is not working and not only for PHP but for many other libraries of python and many other things.

Comment: Unfortunately there are some PECL extensions(http) that simply are not made available on Windows Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 does not natively support PHP code. Are you using [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I assume he is compiling the C source for the PHP compiler/interpreter.